# What's the easiest path to make my extlinux-booted Ubuntu bootable via UEFI?

Tags: ubuntu, uefi, bootloader

I have a single-partition Ubuntu system that's entirely contained in a ext2 filesystem, which is the active partition of its disk (MBR partition table).

It's booted via extlinux, and, obviously, it's legacy boot. It's responsible for loading its vmlinuz and initrd.lz files, and the only thing it does is that, there's no menu.

Newer computers (none of mine, thankfully) don't support legacy anymore, so I'm looking for a way to make it bootable via UEFI.

I don't wish to have any boot menu by itself, nothing fancy. I only want it to become a boot option for UEFI-only computers, and once selected all it's going to do is to boot the Linux on it, no questions asked, just like my extlinux currently does.

So, what's the fastest path for that?

I just want an UEFI loader that loads the vmlinuz and initrd.lz in the partition.

Comment: @John Not necessarily that easy because then I'd need another OS to run said app, not to mention the performance loss. And the fact I use several low-level tools that need access to my actual hardware directly. It can't be virtualized at all.

Comment: @John How exactly could Dual Boot be slow? Once booted the system is running by its own. But anyway, there's *no* Dual Boot anywhere. I don't run any other OS but this one on this machine, it's not dual boot. I just wish it to be bootable via UEFI when I use it on another, newer machine. And then again my software *cannot* run in a virtual machine at all, I need direct access to my physical hardware for my firmware tools.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/747336/653259 Indeed not possible to have it in UEFI mode. And probably no reason at all, other than not wanting to upgrade, to keep such ancient installation. Any UEFI mode only machine is very new so, besides the bootloader, it needs newer drivers and software and yes, a proper OS to support it. Any mainstream distro supports UEFI by default since more than a decade ago.

Comment: @ChanganAuto my installation isn't ancient, its Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS. I made it extlinux only just because I hate grub and I prefer having manual control over it. And It is in fact *POSSIBLE* to make it UEFI bootable because I literally just did. I used syslinux for that and it was *very* easy. I'll post an answer to my own post.

Comment: Great. Looking for it.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a very easy path to make my extlinux-booted ubuntu UEFI bootable: Using Syslinux.

In fact I even managed to make it bootable simultaneously by Legacy and UEFI mode in *some* systems which also scan for UEFI loaders in MBR partitioned-devices.

The solution was very simple: I installed syslinux-efi and syslinux. I made a new partition on my disk, set its type to ef00 (efi partition), formatted it with FAT32 format. And then I made these two folders:

```
<mountpoint>/EFI/boot/
```

Then I copied syslinux files to it:

```
cp -r /usr/lib/syslinux/modules/efi64/* <mountpoint>/EFI/boot/
cp -r /usr/lib/SYSLINUX.EFI/efi64/syslinux.efi* <mountpoint>/EFI/boot/bootx64.efi
```

It's imperative that the name of the folders and efi file (bootx64.efi) are those names, for BIOSes will automatically scan if they exist and add them as a boot option in their menu. It doesn't work with another name unless if you use an EFI manager to add that entry. But for automatic recognition you'll need this.

Then just copy the same vmlinuz and initrd.lz files extlinux was loading into that EFI partition, and copy extlinux.conf to /EFI/boot/syslinux.cfg.

And it's done. It will load vmlinuz and initrd.lz and it boots normally.

And it's still bootable by legacy boot.

You may have a headache if your BIOS ignore your device for being MBR partitioned.

In which case you'd have to convert it from MBR to GPT before creating the EFI partition I mentioned, but everything else will be the same.

Then it's not going to be bootable by legacy boot anymore.

Also, note, nothing here supports secure boot, so far.

So if the machine has secure boot, it will need to be disabled, or some other method will be necessary to make it accept this efi loader.